# scape html from json post request in go

Tags: json, go, escaping, go-templates

I want to scape to html some json in request but it doesn´t work, I get an error when decoding json

```
import (
    "html/template" 
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func anyFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    ri, wo := io.Pipe()
    go template.HTMLEscape(wo, body)   
    var t []customStruct
    json.NewDecoder(ri).Decode(t) //error: Invalid character:'&' looking for beginning of object key string
    ...
}
```

The json coming from the client it´s valid because I´m using "JSON.stringify(data)"
Go 1.9.4

Comment: From the docs of [io.Pipe()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) *"That is, each Write to the PipeWriter blocks until it has satisfied one or more Reads from the PipeReader that fully consume the written data."* Use a goroutine to allow the pipe reader and wirter to work in sync.

Comment: Thanks!, but now I´m getting another error when decoding, it says: "invalid character & looking for beginning of object key string". Should I edit my question?

Comment: That is a json error due to the format you are passing when hitting the api function which is getting in the body. So correct json

Comment: It´s a valid json, from the client I´m using "JSON.stringify(data)" with fetch

Comment: Can you print you body here and show us the output

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue136s6qwwlibqc/Screenshot_4.png?dl=0)   [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9itlxlwchdxdvs2/Screenshot_6.png?dl=0)

Comment: [console in client](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76xbqt1hskuvnsa/Screenshot_11.png?dl=0)----- [client request code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bolrp1oa50htebt/Screenshot_12.png?dl=0)   ----- [print in terminal](https://www.dropbox.com/s/877d8yucggrnch3/Screenshot_5.png?dl=0)  ------ [back end code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9itlxlwchdxdvs2/Screenshot_6.png?dl=0)

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias Why are you passing valid json to `HTMLEscape`? You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: ... https://play.golang.org/p/3NOfKbKDzpN

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias do not link to images unless necessary, it is much better if you update your question with text containing the json data, the struct type definition into which your decoding, and the console/terminal output.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for suggestion, I can see now where I was wrong, I have to scape only the fields from json, not json itself. If you could make it as an answer I will mark it as valid answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not html-escape the whole valid json payload, you are inadvertently invalidating it which causes the json decoding to fail.

If you need to sanitize values contained *in* the valid json, you can do so either after you first unmarshal it, or during the unmarshaling by implementing the `json.Unmarshaler` interface on a custom type which could then sanitize the raw bytes of the value.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the json package need a method to solve this, because it makes repeating the same code with diferent structs, with such a basic problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [GoLang json package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode)

> Decode reads the next JSON-encoded value from its input and stores it
>   in the value pointed to by v.

```
func (dec *Decoder) Decode(v interface{}) error
```

The error is due to decode will take the address to `[]customStruct` while you are passing the value. Change here

```
func anyFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    ri, wo := io.Pipe()
    go template.HTMLEscape(wo, body)   
    var t []customStruct
    json.NewDecoder(ri).Decode(&t)
    ...
}
```

Comment: not working [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/877d8yucggrnch3/Screenshot_5.png?dl=0)  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9itlxlwchdxdvs2/Screenshot_6.png?dl=0)

Comment: then there is something wrong in the format of struct `[]customStruct` in which you are decoding the json. Match for struct fields before encoding the json

Comment: Both fields from request match the struct [item1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jsel327azdrbv76/Screenshot_13.png?dl=0)---[item2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2005eewegaxa7la/Screenshot_14.png?dl=0) ---- [console in client](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76xbqt1hskuvnsa/Screenshot_11.png?dl=0) ----[client request code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bolrp1oa50htebt/Screenshot_12.png?dl=0)  ---[print body in terminal](https://www.dropbox.com/s/877d8yucggrnch3/Screenshot_5.png?dl=0)  ----[back end code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9itlxlwchdxdvs2/Screenshot_6.png?dl=0)